# Passport issues september 2006 - has 'camera' symbol is it valid?

Tags: visas, passports, us-visa-waiver-program

Hi I have a 'camera' symbol on my passport on the front page. My passport was issued to be in September 2006 and is Valid until May 2017 - does that mean my passport is fine to travel to the USA and meets the e passport/biometric requirements to enter the USA. I have an approved ESTA also.
I fly to the USA next week so am rally worried.

Answer (score 2):

If your passport has the [biometric symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biometric_passport) on the front cover, you should not have a problem using it to enter the US. If you are still concerned and you have or know someone with an NFC equipped Android phone, you can download apps from the Google play store that can read the passport information including your photograph over NFC. e.g. [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.innovalor.nfciddocshowcase&hl=en), although there are many others.

Conditions of travel under the Visa Waiver Programme can be found [here](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/visit/visa-waiver-program.html) including the description of the e-passport symbol on the front cover.